# Laravel mailable passing array to blade

Tags: laravel

On my project i made a contact form. It was store details on databse and shows admin panel and sends it to via mail so i cant pass array variables to mailable view.

My controller;

```
$iletisim = new Contact();
$iletisim->ad = $request->input('ad');
$iletisim->soyad =$request->input('soyad');
$iletisim->email = $request->input('email');
$iletisim->mesaj = $request->input('mesaj');
$iletisim->save();
$gonder = array( 'gonderen'=>$request->input('ad'),
    'email'=>$request->input('email'),
    'mesaj'=>$request->input('mesaj')
);

Mail::send(new ContactMail($gonder));

Session::flash('success', 'Mesajınız Gönderilmiştir. En kısa sürede dönüş sağlanacaktır.');
return back();
```

}

My Contact.php

```
public $bilgiler;

    public function __construct($gonder)
    {
        $this->bilgiler = $gonder;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('homepage.emails.contact')->with(['bilgiler'=>$this->bilgiler]);
    }
```

and my blade file

```
@component('mail::message')
# New Contact Form

{{$bilgiler->ad}}


Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

Where is my mistake can you help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to add `->with(['bilgiler'=>$this->bilgiler]);` since `$bilgiger` is public property. [All public properties of Mailable are available in Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#view-data)

Also, since it's an array, you need to access it with:

```
$bilgiger['gonderen']
```

The `$bilgiler->gonderen` syntax is for objects, not for arrays. Also, you don't have `id` in the array.

And the last thing is you're using markdown email, so use the `markdown()` method:

```
return $this->markdown('homepage.emails.contact');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply friend. But do i need id? And when trying to do your suggestion im getting this error No hint path defined for [mail]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\download\resources\views\homepage\emails\contact.blade.php) I dont understand what means hint path

Comment: @sadri you're using markdown, so use the `markdown()` instead of `view()`. I've updated the answer.